# json status is not entering in if

Tags: ios, json

i have this method to login via json array , it's all ok but it's not entering in

```
if(json2 == 0)
```

but in NSLog show me that it's value is 0 , how can i resolve this ? the method is working but it doesent enter in that if.

```
-(void)loginAPICall
{

    NSString *device_name = @"Iphone";
    NSString *device_modelname = @"5";
    NSString *gcm_id = @"1234567890";
    NSString *user = _user.text;
    NSString *pass = _pass.text;
   //  SENDING A POST JSON
    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"device_name=%@&device_modelname=%@&gcm_id=%@&username=%@&password=%@", device_name, device_modelname, gcm_id, user, pass];

    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://192.168.1.110/project/api"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];


    NSURLResponse *requestResponse;
    NSData *requestHandler = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&requestResponse error:nil];
    NSError *error;
    NSMutableDictionary *getJsonData = [NSJSONSerialization
                                        JSONObjectWithData:requestHandler
                                        options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                        error:&error];

    if( error )
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    else {
        NSArray *json = getJsonData[@"login"];



        for ( NSDictionary *jsn in json )
        {
            NSLog(@"id: %@ ", jsn[@"id_user"] );

        }

        NSArray *json2 = getJsonData[@"status"];
        if(json2 == 0){
            NSLog(@"Cannot login");
        }
        NSLog(@"value:%@",json2);

    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your json data ?

Comment: array ==0 what r u doing ?

Comment: What does the NSLog tell you *exactly*???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saying that the object return by `getJsonData[@"status"];` is an array, but then you are check if with an `integer` :

```
NSArray *json2 = getJsonData[@"status"];
if(json2 == 0){
   NSLog(@"Cannot login");
}
```

If you need to check whether the array return by status has values do it like thisL:

```
NSArray *json2 = getJsonData[@"status"];
if([json2 count] == 0){
   NSLog(@"Cannot login");
}
```

If the object return for the node status is an integer then try this:

```
NSNumber *json2 = getJsonData[@"status"];
if([json2 integerValue] == 0){
   NSLog(@"Cannot login");
}
```

Comment: He should also *not* be checking `error`, but for `getJsonData` instead.